# lvconvert between different volumegroups - LVM

Tags: lvm

There are 2 lvs which are in the VG Raid. This two lvs should be an LVM Mirror. This 2 lvs should be mirrored in another VG called non-Raid.

```
sudo vgs
  VG       #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree 
  Raid       4  16   0 wz--n-  7,27t  2,60t
  non-Raid   4   5   0 wz--n- <3,60t 25,23g
```

Is LVM able to do this?

Comment: Do you mean that for each LV you want a four-way mirror with two legs in each VG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want you should start from scratch:

1. Create LV (w/o filesystem) on RAID VG with number of copies 2
2. Create LV (w/o filesystem) on Non RAID VG with number of copies 2 (or not, depend if you want 4 way mirror)
3. Create those volumes as PV
4. Create new VG with those PVs
5. Create LVs in this new VG with number of copies 2
6. Create filesystems on those new LVs

Comment: A VGs only for the 2 lvs?
This sounds very inflexible...

Comment: @JokerGermany.de, this is based on your requirements :)

Comment: Ah ok i understand
A VG on the old VGs oO
Thats sound weird, i will give it a try...
Can i access the data with for example with testdisk when i search for it on the plain hardware?
(If nothing works...)

Comment: @JokerGermany.de, I did not get you about access data, can you explain.

Comment: @JokerGermany.de, I edit my answer to correct the number of LVs you need.

Comment: I want to get on my data, even if nothing works.
I tested if i can save the daten if i do
"testdisk /dev/sdc9" and then list files.
And yes it works.
Thats the Reason for using non-Raid...

Comment: BTW: Why should i create two lvs on each volume group?
I created only one and then split it with point 5

Comment: What i did:  
sudo lvcreate -L 275GB -n Wichtig Raid  
sudo lvcreate -L 275GB -n Wichtig non-Raid  
sudo vgcreate Wichtig /dev/Raid/Wichtig /dev/non-Raid/Wichtig  
sudo lvcreate -m1 -L 250GB -n Bilder Wichtig  
sudo lvcreate -m1 -l 100%FREE -n Wichtige-Daten Wichtig   
Then i copied the data with dd

Comment: @JokerGermany.de, if the data is on filesystem you can use `cp` instead of `dd` :)